# How to override regular binary operators such as +, -, *, / in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I override common operators such as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `<`, `==`, `>`, etc. for a class?

Comment: Ahh! these are already a methods.

Comment: What if I want to override them to serve any special need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how they are overridden, they are not necessarily binary.

```
class Foo
  def +; :plus end
  def -; :minus end
  def *; :asterisk end
  def /; :slash end
  def <; :lt end
  def ==; :eq end
  def >; :gt end
end

Foo.new.+ # => :plus
Foo.new.- # => :minus
Foo.new.* # => :asterisk
Foo.new./ # => :slash
Foo.new.< # => :lt
Foo.new.== # => :eq
Foo.new.> # => :gt
```

Comment: 'necessarily binary' what that means?

Comment: Usually a binary operator requires two variables to work with. For instance, the operation `a + b` is binary because it requires `a` and `b` to produce a result. However in ruby, since operators are also methods, they don't necessarily need two arguments to produce a result as sawa demonstrated. His operators do not take any argument, yet still produce results.

Comment: Continuing from my previous example, when you do `a + b` in Ruby, you're really doing `a.+(b)`. Following sawa's example, if you were to do `a = Foo.new`, you could then call `a.+` and get `:plus` as a result!